# Абзацы при прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь, оформление-текста, абзац

В разделе об абзацах при прямой речи есть такое правило:

3. Текст автора, не относящийся к говорящему лицу и непосредственно следующий за прямой речью, начинается с абзаца:

**— Я уверен, — продолжал я, — что княжна в тебя уж влюблена. Он покраснел до ушей и надулся** (Л.).

Здесь под "Текст автора, не относящийся к говорящему лицу и непосредственно следующий за прямой речью, начинается с абзаца" имеются в виду слова "Он покраснел до ушей и надулся"?

Но они же в приведенном примере не начинаются с абзаца.

Вроде бы, следуя правилу, должно быть так:

**— Я уверен, — продолжал я, — что княжна в тебя уж влюблена.**

**Он покраснел до ушей и надулся** (Л.).

Answer (score 3):

А где Вы этот пример нашли? В тексте Лермонтова, по-моему, абзац есть. Может, это издержки перевода в онлайн? Абзац нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Посмотрела в бумажном Розентале: там всё правильно с абзацами.

Answer (score 3):

К великому сожалению, это не издержки перевода, это такая статья:
http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/48854/75/Rozental'_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html ,
 в которой "обозначилась" ошибка.

И  еще одна (пар.52 п.3):
https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html

**— Я уверен, — продолжал я, — что княжна в тебя уж влюблена!

Он покраснел до ушей и надулся.**
http://evo-lutio.livejournal.com/396108.html
(ТАК правильно.)