# Обособление вводных слов с союзами: у Розенталя противоречие

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, вводные-слова

> Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе а): <…> Расчёты были сделаны наскоро, **а следовательно**, и неточно. <…>
>
> <...>
>
> Однородный член предложения, стоящий после вводных слов *а значит*, *а следовательно*, не обособляется (т. е. запятая после него не ставится): <...> Эта схема, **а следовательно** и весь проект в целом нуждается в проверке.

Отрывок взят [отсюда](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122). Противоречие или в предложениях есть какое‑то семантическое различие, которое обуславливает разное обособление и которое я не замечаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**НЕТ** у Розенталя никаких противоречий и никаких семантических различий, обуславливающих разное обособление. Есть **правильная** формулировка, но одновременно — **НЕПРАВИЛЬНОЕ пунктуационное оформление** в электронной версии.

Смотрим раздел пятый (в самом конце).
Однородный член предложения, стоящий после вводных слов *а значит, а следовательно,* не обособляется (т. е. запятая после него не ставится):
*В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит*** [должна быть запятая на общих основаниях!] ***и сила приёма*** [нет запятой — именно о НЕЙ речь в правиле!] *увеличивается во много раз; Эта схема, **а следовательно*** [должна быть запятая!] ***и весь проект в целом*** [не нужна запятая!] *нуждается в проверке.*

Подтверждение имеется [**здесь**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html) (Вводные слова, словосочетания и предложения).
Раздел третий, пункт пятый (выделен розовым):
Однородный член предложения, стоящий после вводных слов ***а значит, а следовательно,*** не обособляется, то есть запятая после него не ставится.
Например: *В результате **сила** электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит,** и **сила** приёма увеличивается во много раз; Эта **схема**, **а следовательно,** и весь **проект** в целом нуждается в проверке.*

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: НЕТ у Розенталя никаких противоречий..._ === Есть. Такое разное "пунктуационное оформление" одного и того же предложения с "а значит" имеет место не только в электронной версии, но и в бумажных справочниках Розенталя. К сожалению... А то, что Вы привели в качестве "подтверждения" — это не Розенталь.

Comment: @slava1947 Я считаю, что ответ верен по сути. Даже если в каком-то издании нет запятой, это, вероятно досадная опечатка. В изданиях 1984, 1988, 1994 годов запятая присутствует. Других не могу найти пока. Не подскажете, в каких изданиях обсуждаемая запятая отсутствует?

Comment: _grizzly: Не подскажете, в каких изданиях обсуждаемая запятая отсутствует?_ === К примеру, здесь: Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. 2-е изд., перераб. М., 2008.

Comment: @slava1947 Вот здесь с запятой: https://7lafa.com/pageanswer.php?id=44189. И здесь: https://in.lit.msu.ru/media/Ulysses/olga.fedorova/2018/Вводные_слова_словосочетания_и_предложения.pdf. Завтра (уже сегодня) могу стоптаться в библиотеку (благо — работаю совсем рядом), посмотреть "конкретно глазьями"...

Comment: Такие ляпы иногда встречаются: формулируем и рассуждаем правильно, а "текстово" оформляем неверно. Вот (как пример) вопрос на нашем сайте: **Абзацы при прямой речи.**  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430813/Абзацы-при-прямой-речи/430820#430820

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо, действительно. Нашёл это издание (в электронном виде). Я считаю, что год издания очень важен, поскольку у нас звучат фразы "это Розенталь / это не Розенталь". Желательно избегать такого контекста, в котором 2008 г. издания ассоциируется лично с Розенталем. Будем считать, что он бы этой опечатки не допустил.

Comment: А если однородный член имеет добавочный характер, возможно оформление по типу присоединительной конструкции: _В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, а значит и сила приёма, увеличивается во много раз; Эта схема, а следовательно и весь проект, в целом нуждается в проверке._?

Comment: Где тогда читать "правильного" Розенталя? На Evartist.narod.ru корректный справочник?