# Обособление вводного слова "а значит"

Tags: вводные-слова

Из правил Розенталя: однородный член предложения, стоящий после вводных слов ***а значит, а следовательно***, не обособляется (т. е. запятая после него не ставится):

**В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, а значит и сила приёма увеличивается во много раз. [См. § 12, п. 7.]**

В параграфе, на который ссылаются авторы, есть идентичный пример:

**В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, а значит, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз.**

В одинаковых примерах разная пунктуация, то есть в первом примере отсутствует запятая после вводного слова. Вопрос: какой из вариантов является правильным?

Comment: Максим, Ваш вопрос уже обсуждался на сайте. Посмотрите: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447950/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5/447952#447952 (Обособление вводных слов с союзами: у Розенталя противоречие.) **А значит** обособляется, а после однородного члена **сила приема** запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

См. § 12, п. 7

Давайте посмотрим: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

7. При наличии **вводных слов**, связывающих однородные члены предложения, после последнего из них запятая не ставится: *В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, **а значит**, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз.* Странный, если хотите — вызывающий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих.

Вроде бы всё на месте. Вводное сочетание ***а значит*** обособлено, после **последнего однородного члена** ***сила приема*** запятая не стоит.

Правило можно легко объяснить, убрав вводное сочетание: В результате ***сила электромагнитного поля*** проходящих сигналов и ***сила приёма*** увеличиваются во много раз.  Здесь союз И связывает два однородных члена.

Примечание

Отношения между однородными членами могут быть равноправные по смыслу, но в то же время могут **дополнительно дифференцироваться  с помощью вводных слов и наречий.** В данном случае вводное сочетание вносит дополнительное значение следствия.