# Где взять пример?

Tags: синтаксис

Есть правило:

> "Вводные слова и сочетания, стоящие на границе однородных членов или
> частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову
> или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой: Послышался резкий
> стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня. А. Чехов, Невеста"

- примеры для этого правила написаны только по сложному предложению, можно привести пример, где вводное слово бы стояло на границе однородных членов, будут ли играть в таком случае какую-то роль союзы, находящиеся на этой границе?

Comment: А у Чехова стоит запятая:  Послышался резкий стук, должно быть, сорвалась ставня.  https://ilibrary.ru/text/1184/p.4/index.html  Нехорошо править классику, как делается в ПАС,  По  правилам 1956 года вводное слово (но уже в качестве присоединительного союза) могло относиться к обособленным уточняющим оборотам.  У Розенталя такого оформления тоже нет. Необособленное вводное слово – это уже не вводное слово. А это оформление вводного слова  у Грамоты: Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит. И везде обособление (вводных слов).

Comment: Это они сделали реформу. См. у Розенталя в примечании 1 (там про однородные): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122,4

Comment: @oleedd
Кто они? Я смотрела Розенталя,  он не предлагает присоединять вводные слова к однородным членами и при этом не обособлять их. Если же возникает необходимость, то однородный член переходит в уточняющий, и тогда это возможно (вводное слово меняет свой статус).

Comment: @Sharon *Кто они?* — составители ПАС. Мне тоже не нравится, хотя их понять можно. Просто расширили область применения правила. Но они должны не реформы делать, а в правилах отображать то, как делает большинство авторов, а здесь по факту только косят под это. Статус не меняется, вводное слово тоже обособляется, но с одной стороны, в обстоятельство не превращается, в этом случае уж точно.

Comment: @oleedd Во что-нибудь да превращается, обычно в присоединительный союз. Мне у Розенталя один пример не нравится – с вводными словами "а значит, а следовательно". Как-то не по делу он их лепит к однородным членам.  Практику письма, конечно, надо учитывать. Я часто замечаю, что правила ПАС не применяются в реальных текстах, субъективных решений там много.  Уровень понимания языка уже не тот, что у настоящих академиков.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, в правилах чётко говорится: **вводное слово** не отделяется запятой от обособленного оборота. Сказали бы, если бы выступало чем-то другим. Такого рода погрешностей в правилах нет. Надеюсь, что вы понимаете, зачем это правило существует. Союзом может выступать, когда на границе простых предложений.

Comment: @oleedd  Мне кажется, у меня в бумажной книге ошибка (не обособлены вводные слова "а значит, а следовательно" (а значит и сила приема...)  Это конец п. 5. А на электронный сайт меня антивирус не пускает.

Comment: @Sharon Это не антивирус, сам сайт не работает, сайт со справочником Лопатина тоже (несколько дней уже). Сайты закрываются, если затраты превышают прибыль. Можете использовать сохранённые копии Google.

Comment: @oleedd А это как сделать?

Comment: @Sharon https://i.imgur.com/fif2LNv.png Но оно обычно очень долго грузится, не могу понять почему. Обычно нажимаю вверху на "Текстовая версия", тогда ждать не надо, но только текст открывается.

Comment: @oleedd Не получается...  Ну ладно, спасибо, завтра попробую найти  на Google.

Comment: @Sharon В Яндексе тоже есть. Может быть не нормальный вид, а просто текст на белом фоне.

Comment: @oleedd Я в Гугле нашла что-то подходящее, в виде книги (страницу приходится искать). Ну и что? Там тоже ошибка, нет обособления вводного слова, а в  его же ссылке на § 12, п. 7   есть обособление. Посмотрите, у вас есть?

Comment: @Sharon Это уже обсуждали: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447950 1959 год: https://i.imgur.com/BeZqqCq.png

Comment: @oleedd Да, спасибо, прошло мимо меня. Ну значит, все на месте, запятая должна быть, а то я уже обвиняла Розенталя в некорректном решении. И ясна общая позиция для сочинительной и бессоюзной линейной (без обособления) связи как однородных членов, так и предложений: никаких необособленных вводных слов, как в ПАС. В грамматике это называется дифференцированные однородные отношения с использованием наречий, частиц, вводных слов, подчинительных союзов (хотя и)

Comment: @Sharon Что-то не очень мне нравятся эти примеры ("*сила приёма увеличивается*" надо читать без паузы, иначе обособленный оборот). Там не союз И, а частица (из-за вводного), это можно понять по: *сила электромагнитного поля, а значит, [что] и сила приёма*. А необособление оборота способствует тому, чтобы было союзом (*сила поля и сила приёма*). Эта нестыковка всё портит. Если оборот закрыть, то запятая будет, потому что в начале не вводное слово, а союз и двусмысленности, из-за которой существует это правило, нет: *...приходящих сигналов, а значит, и сила приема, увеличивается во много раз.*

Comment: @Sharon Вот то, на что Розенталь в конце ссылается: https://i.imgur.com/zZb0iMO.png Эти примеры гораздо удачнее.

Comment: @oleedd Я уже говорила, что однородный член может при нужном значении стать обособленным (уточняющим или присоединительным), тогда вводное слово может не обособляться от него по правилам. Но если между однородными членами тесная смысловая связь, то этого делать не следует.  Связь тогда  остается однородной,  а вводное слово обособляется отдельно.

Comment: @Sharon *Связь тогда остается однородной* — с этим можно поспорить, там всё сложно, всё равно присоединение (смотрите примеры с "да и"). Вообще здесь перелом конструкции (это точно), не всегда он удачен, не должно быть нестыковок, всё должно быть плавно. Есть ли у Лопатина такое? Стандартным это назвать нельзя, такое бывает редко.

Comment: @oleedd Меня не очень интересуют частные вопросы с их конкретикой.  Важно следующее: что-то должно обособляться: или вводное слово, или весь присоединительный оборот. А это уже решается по месту. А вы частности любите))  Лучше на мой вопрос ответьте, вы там тоже замешаны.

Comment: @Sharon А мы здесь не с частным разбираемся? На общие вопросы отвечать не хотят, потому что это сложно и скучно (надо всё расписывать). Здесь не вводное слово, а союз + вводное слово: https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=www.old-punctum.ru%2fpunctum.php%3fsid%3d1029&d=4697277038227557&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=SAw2NN9iMr9YE30eCLemAIeysjER-0yq Поэтому вводное слово не в начале оборота, и это вроде бы обсуждали, вряд ли получится найти.

Comment: Запишите ваше предложение и расставьте знаки, а я их объясню. ОК?

Comment: @Sharon Какое ещё предложение? Говорил за примеры Розенталя, про то, что они не особо удачны, потому что есть нестыковка с И. У Лопатина есть такое? Странно, что такая структура понравилась Розенталю настолько, что аж в справочник добавил.